# How do I distribute a large volume of data to worker nodes in Apache Spark (PySpark)?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, vector-search

Playing around with vector search algorithms and want to split my index over multiple nodes. When building the index, currently my approach is:

1. Pass a single numpy array containing all the vectors into my SparkIndex
2. Split the array into multiple chunks, approx. equal sized
3. Create an RDD of the chunks
4. use `mapPartitions` to create an index partition on each worker node from the respective chunk in the RDD partition

However, let's say I want to build a larger index where I can't store the whole thing as one numpy array in memory to start. Assuming that my to-be-indexed vectors are stored in a CSV file (or similar) to start, I was thinking that one approach could be:

1. Split the CSV file into N partitions, where N is the number of worker nodes.
2. Save each CSV-partition to one worker node
3. Instead of passing numpy array chunks to worker nodes via `parallelize` RDD creation, have my mapped function read CSV-partition and create the index partition.

I'm a beginner to Apache Spark / PySpark so I was wondering if this approach makes sense or not, and if there is a better/recommended way to do it.

If it matters, currently I'm running spark locally (creating spark session with `.master("local[16]")` but I plan to try set up a cluster sometime.

Comment: Split the csv into P > N partitions so that parallel reading of data by spark happens. Then depending on your cluster resources, you can split the dataframe into N partitions using repartition. Don't worry about distribution of those parititons on worker nodes. That's spark's job and its beauty. Get an overview of how Spark does things from somewhere.